# Wordpress 3 latest blog post in Bootsrap4 carousel

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display the featured image, title and the beginning of the 3 latest blog post in a Bootstrap4 carousel.
The carousel is displaying, with the desired content however it stays on the first post.
Not sliding either automatically nor using the indicators and prev and next arrow.

````
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h3 class="LatestBlog">Replace later</h3>

                <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderyby' => 'post_id',
                        'order' => 'ASC' )); 
                        ?>
                <div id="carouselBlogPosts" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <?php $count = 0; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                            <li data-target="#carouselBlogPostsIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count ?>" class="<?php if($count == '0'){ echo 'active'; } ?>"></li>
                        <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </ol>

                    <?php $count = 0; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   
                         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item  <?php if($count == '0'){ echo 'active';} ?>">
                            <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>" alt="">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 10);?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselBlogPosts" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselBlogPosts" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>```

I'm probably making a mistake with the class="active" but can't see where it is and how to solve it.
````

Comment: For an unknown reason the carousel in working when I remove ```<div class="carousel-inner">```
If someone can explain that would be awesome as this class is in use in Bootstrap4 documentation and I have other carousel working with it so this is driving me completely nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was the `<div class="carousel-inner">` being inside the while loop it should be outside!!! The following code is working

````
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h3 class="LatestBlog">Replace later</h3>

                <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'post', 
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderyby' => 'post_id',
                        'order' => 'ASC' )); 
                        ?>
                <div id="carouselBlogPosts" class="carousel slide text-center d-flex align-items-center" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators carousel-indicators2">
                        <?php $count = 0; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                            <li data-target="#carouselBlogPostsIndicators" data-slide-to="<?php echo $count ?>" class="<?php if($count == '0'){ echo 'active'; } ?>"></li>
                        <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <?php $count = 0; while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>   
                         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

                        <div class="carousel-item  <?php if($count == '0'){ echo 'active';} ?>">
                            <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>" alt="">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
                                <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 10);?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
                    </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselBlogPosts" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselBlogPosts" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>```
````